# MVC4 - ActionLink to either Create() or, if already existing, Edit(Id)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink, html.actionlink

I would like an action link that says "set user default".  There's a possibility the database does not already have the UserDetails stored for the user who clicks the link.  If this is the case, I would like to direct the user to the Create view when they can save a new object.

If the UserDetails already exists for the user, I would like to direct the user to their Edit(id) page and load their existing UserDetails from the database.

Basically I need an ActionLink that points to a different view based on some information.

What is the preferred/standard way in MVC to accomplish this?

**Existing Record**

```
@Html.ActionLink("set user default", "Edit", "User")
```

**Non-Existing Record**

```
@Html.ActionLink("set user default", "Create", "User")
```

This was an attempt I made however it didn't work since EditOrCreate needs to be a view - ideally this scenario would not require the creation of another view.

```
    public ActionResult EditOrCreate()
    {
        User user = Get(User.Identity.Name);

        if (user != null)
            Edit(user);
        else
            Create();
    }
```

Comment: what is ``Edit()`` and `Create()` , show their dfinition

Comment: One option might be to set the action link to `Edit` and then in the `Edit()` method, do the check, and if `user` is `null`, `RedirectToAction("Create");`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Edit(user) and Create() are the standard MVC public ActionResult methods.

Comment: so they are not working for you?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I considered this but didn't know if directing-checking-redirecting was poor practice on the web...

Comment: I don't think it would be considered 'poor' practice (for example, usually when you post to an edit method you then redirect somewhere else or return the view based on checking `ModelState.IsValid`). Although personally I would do the check when you generate the view, and then render one link or the other with a more descriptive display text

Comment: @StephenMuecke good insight - thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by having action link to SetUserDefault action method such as

```
@Html.ActionLink("set user default", "SetUserDefault", "User")
```

Inside the action method detect the user type and then redirect the user to the right action

```
public ActionResult SetUserDefault()
{
    User currentUser = Get(User.Identity.Name);

    if (currentUser != null)
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = currentUser.Id });
    else
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Comment: This worked, however I needed to add the returns and the param for the Id.  Thank you!